# How to print in if statement in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

This is the code I tried

```
fun printsl([], k) = true
        | printsl(h::t) = if k > h then print(h) andalso printsl(t);
```

But when I run the code, i get the following error

```
= stdIn:4.68-7.8 Error: syntax error: deleting  SEMICOLON ID
stdIn:8.1 Error: syntax error found at EOF
```

The goal of the function is to print any number in the list that is less than the value `k`

Comment: There must be an `else` branch  - the conditional is an *expression*, not a statement, so must produce a value in all cases. Also, all definition clauses must take the same number and types of parameters - you have one that takes `('a list * 'b)` and one that takes `int list` (and `k` is not bound in that clause). Perhaps you should look at an introduction to SML?

Comment: Also, the type of `print` is `string -> unit`. It can't print integers, and the result can't be an operand of `andalso`.

Comment: On a side note, if this is an exercise in an introduction to SML and it says "output", that's probably in the sense of returning a value, not of printing anything.

Comment: You will probably find the function `Int.toString : int -> string` helpful if you do need to print.

Answer (score 1):

A few things wrong here. Let's start with your function signature.

On the first line, your function takes 2 parameters, an empty list and whatever the type of `k` is (it is not important yet). Then on the second line, the function takes just one parameter, a non-empty list.

The two lines should match to look like:

```ml
fun printsl([],   k) = ...
  | printsl(h::t, k) = ...
```

Now let's think about the use of `andalso`. `andalso` is an operator which takes two booleans and returns a bool. It can be considered to have the signature `bool * bool -> bool`.

Your usage `print(h) andalso printsl(t)` does not match this signature.

The type of `print` is `string -> unit`, so the type of `print(h)` is `unit` (assuming `h` to be a string). As such, the usage of `andalso` is incorrect as the types on each side are not bools.

Instead of using `andalso`, we can simply execute both statements `(print(h); printsl(t, k))`. Sequences like this are expressions which return the last value. That is to say `(x; y; z)` returns `z`.

```ml
fun printsl([],   k) = true
  | printsl(h::t, k) = if h < k then (print(h); printsl(t, k));
```

However, this is still broken as the if-else construct in SML is an expression and *must* have a matching else, so you could use either of the following:

```ml
fun printsl([],   k) = true
  | printsl(h::t, k) =
    if h < k then (print(h); printsl(t))
    else printsl(t, k);
```

```ml
fun printsl([],   k) = true
  | printsl(h::t, k) = (
    if h < k then print(h) else ();
    printsl(t, k)
  );
```

I personally prefer the latter as it prevents repetition of `printsl`.

This code will compile, but the signature is wrong. As we use `h` directly as a parameter of `print`, its type is inferred to be a `string`. This means that the compiler determines `printsl` to have type `string list * string -> bool`, whereas we are aiming for `int list * int -> bool`.

This can be corrected by changing the call `print(h)` to `print(Int.toString h)`, giving us:

```ml
fun printsl([],   k) = true
  | printsl(h::t, k) = (
    if h < k then print(Int.toString h) else ();
    printsl(t, k)
  );
```

This is now a function which will print all values in the given list which are less than `k`, but it always returns true. This provides no extra information so I would be inclined to change the signature to `int list * int -> unit`, giving us (finally):

```ml
fun printsl([],   k) = ()
  | printsl(h::t, k) = (
    if h < k then print(Int.toString h) else ();
    printsl(t, k)
  );
```

This entire program could also be written in a more functional manner using `List.app` and `List.filter`.

```ml
fun printsl (xs, k) =
  List.app
    (fn y => print (Int.toString y))
    (List.filter
      (fn x => x < k)
      xs);
```